# Qt on Android: qmlimportscanner: No such file or directory

Tags: android, qt, qt5

I am trying to build my Qt app for Android using Qt 5.14 which allows the possibility to create an app bundle that allows to deploy one single file for different architecture. My app builds fine with 5.13.1 but when I try with Qt 5.14 I get this:

```
qmlimportscanner: No such file or directory: "/home/casa/build-NotiziePLUS-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_0_for_Android-Release/qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc"
Invalid json output from qmlimportscanner.
```

I am not really sure what the source of this error could be, I assume it must have to do with translation file but that's just a guess.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81477. And why it asks for `qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc` which we do not have is not clear?!